# Can't authenticate towards SOAP service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service from an ASP.NET Core Library project.

I have installed the Mictosoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider that has created the proxy classes for me, but I have a problem with the authentication.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

var address = new EndpointAddress(@"https://myserviceaddress.asmx");
var client = new TestApiClient(binding, address);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testusername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "testpassword";
var result = await client.GetDataAsync(params);
```

I have tried some different approaches, but I either get Unauthorized, or variants of this: `The value 'TransportWithMessageCredential' is not supported in this context for the binding security property 'securityMode'.`.

I think I'm also supposed to set some properties on `binding.Security.Message`, but the only property that exist on `binding.Security` is `Transport` and `Mode`.

Anyone know how to set this up correctly?

Are there any other better ways of consuming the SOAP service from ASP.NET Core? I would love a dynamic way that don't have to create the proxy classes, but I can live with the proxies if I have to, but I need to be able to authenticate with a user and password, and I have to use https.

Comment: It seems that `TransportWithMessageCredential` is not supported in .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8

Comment: @ØyvindBråthen, did you get anywhere with this? I am stuck on the same issue.

Comment: @ØyvindBråthen could you figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

After struggling many days with the same issue, because .Net core has a very limited support till date of this answer,  I managed to solve it by building the whole envelope myself and using [SimpleSoapClient](https://github.com/gravity00/SimpleSOAPClient).

I will try to go through all needed steps, step by step with a simple example. because each step has its own issues that needs to be solved.

Let us assume that your model is a Cat.

```
 public class Cat
    {
        public int Lives { get; set; }
    }
```

Your entire envelop model will look like:

```
public class Envelope
{
    public EnvelopeHeader Header { get; set; }
    public EnvelopeBody Body { get; set; }
}
public class EnvelopeHeader
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public Security Security { get; set; }
}


[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
public class Security
{
    public SecurityUsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
}


[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public  class SecurityUsernameToken
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public SecurityUsernameTokenPassword Password { get; set; }
    [XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}


[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public  class SecurityUsernameTokenPassword
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public  class EnvelopeBody
{
    public Cat Cat{ get; set; }
}
```

P.S: do not forget to include XML namespaces where needed in your body.

Next step is serializing your Envelop model into XML string.

```
string xml;
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
     {
       XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
       names.Add("", "");//add your needed namespaces here
       XmlSerializer cs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
       var myEnv = new Envelope()
        {
         Header = new EnvelopeHeader()
          {
           Security = new Security()
            {
              UsernameToken = new SecurityUsernameToken()
               {
                Username = "",
                Password = new SecurityUsernameTokenPassword()
                {
                 Type = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText",//update type to match your case
                 Value = ""
                }
               }
              }
             },
             Body = new EnvelopeBody()
             {
              Cat = new Cat() { Lives = 7 }
             }
            };
            cs.Serialize(writer, myEnv, names);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
          }
     }
```

Finally send your XML envelop using:

```
  SoapEnvelope responseEnvelope = null;
        using (var client = SoapClient.Prepare().WithHandler(new DelegatingSoapHandler()
        {
            OnHttpRequestAsyncAction = async (z, x, y) =>
            {
                x.Request.Content = new StringContent(xml , Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            }
        }))
        {
                responseEnvelope = client.SendAsync("url", "action",SoapEnvelope.Prepare()).Result;
        }
```

Please note that you need to update many options according to your case.
My case was password of type "PasswordText" in the WSSE Security Header with WCF.

Answer (score 3):

Message security (`TransportWithMessageCredential` on `BasicHttpBinding`) is not yet supported in WCF on .NET Core 2.0.

Reference:

- Supported features in v2: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md
- Known issues of v2: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/releases/tag/v2.0.0
- GitHub issues:

  - https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8
  - https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2211

Comment: update per github: `TransportWithMessageCredential ` mode on `BasicHttpBinding` is now supported

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling SSL on IIS? Enabling SSL will make your service listen on both HTTP & HTTPS. your client needs to purchase SSL cert. for this

Comment: It's not my service. It's an external service that I want to consume, so this won't help me much.