# Calling a SOAP service in .net Core

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core

I´m porting a .net 4.6.2 code to a **.net Core project**, that calls a SOAP service. In the new code I´m using C# (because of some config reasons I just can´t remember why right now).

But I´m getting the following exception.

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://someurl.com/ws/Thing.pub.ws:Something. 
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. 
>   This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). 
>   See server logs for more details.

The code that is throwing it is

```
try
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://someurl.com/ws/TheEndpoint.pub.ws:AService"));

    var thing= new TheEndpoint.AService_PortTypeClient(binding, endpoint);
    thing.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "usrn";
    thing.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "passw";

    var response = await thing.getSomethingAsync("id").ConfigureAwait(false);

}
finally
{
    await thing.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Based on the old config where it works calling the service is like this, **what am I missing**?

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="TheEndpoint_pub_ws_AService_Binder" closeTimeout="00:02:00"
        openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://someurl.com/ws/Thing.pub.ws:AService"
      binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="TheEndpoint_pub_ws_AService_Binder"
      contract="TheEndpoint.AService_PortType" name="TheEndpoint_pub_ws_AService_Port" />
</client>
```

I´m just unable to find lot of information on this online. Hope you can help me.

**UPDATE**
Per Sixto Saez suggestion I got the endpoint to reveal its error and it is

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="Integration Server", encoding="UTF-8"'.

I´ll try to find out what to do and post the result here if successful.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok now I tried to move to the new syntax with this code here

```
ChannelFactory<IAService> factory = null;
IAService serviceProxy = null;
Binding binding = null;

try
{
   binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);

   factory = new ChannelFactory<IAService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://someurl.com/ws/TheEndpoint.pub.ws:AService")));            
   factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "usrn";
   factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "passw";

   serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

   var result = await serviceProxy.getSomethingAsync("id").ConfigureAwait(false);

    factory.Close();
    ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();  
}
catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
{
    //error caught here
    throw;
}
```

but I still get the same (slightly different) error. It now has 'Anonymous' instead of 'Basic' and is now missing ", encoding="UTF-8" at the end.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="Integration Server"'.

**Is the problem at my side or the servers?**

Obviously my SOAP "skills" are greatly lacking now days, but I have just about tried every config combo I can think of with this new approach without luck. Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The error seems like  a server-side issue. On the client-side, it is not clear if the `Thing.Authorization_PortTypeClient` class encapsulates creation of a `ChannelFactory` and generation of a `Channel` instance. See this [test code](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/tests/Scenarios/Binding/Http/BasicHttpBindingTests.4.0.0.cs) for how to create and call a WCF client in .NET Core. This [GitHub repo for WCF client libraries](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/) may contain what you are looking for, documentation-wise.

Comment: Thank you @SixtoSaez. I updated the question. But now I get another error I just can´t find out what really means. I have contacted the server people to chek if there is something wrong on their side but if you have any insights I would appreciate all you have to give.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696777/5077196

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Ok this answer is for those who are trying to connect **to a WCF** service **from a .net Core** project.

Here is the solution to **my** problem, using the new .net Core WCF syntax/library.

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = null;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = null;
ChannelFactory<IAService> factory = null;
IAService serviceProxy = null;

try
{
    basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
    basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://someurl.com/ws/TheEndpoint.pub.ws:AService"));
    factory = new ChannelFactory<IAService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "usrn";
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "passw";
    serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

    using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)serviceProxy))
    {
        var result = await serviceProxy.getSomethingAsync("id").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    factory.Close();
    ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
}
catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
{
     throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // *** ENSURE CLEANUP (this code is at the WCF GitHub page *** \\
    CloseCommunicationObjects((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy, factory);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I got the following exception using the code above

> This OperationContextScope is being disposed out of order.

Which seems to be [something that is broken](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2512) (or needs addressing) by the WCF team.

So I had to do the following to make it work (based on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2475))

```
basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

factory = new ChannelFactory<IAService_PortType>(basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://someurl.com/ws/TheEndpoint.pub.ws:AService")));
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "usern";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "passw";
serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Open();
var opContext = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)serviceProxy);
var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current; // Optional if there's no way this might already be set
OperationContext.Current = opContext;

try
{
    var result = await serviceProxy.getSomethingAsync("id").ConfigureAwait(false);

    // cleanup
    factory.Close();
    ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
}
finally
{
  // *** ENSURE CLEANUP *** \\
  CloseCommunicationObjects((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy, factory);
  OperationContext.Current = prevOpContext; // Or set to null if you didn't capture the previous context
}
```

But your requirements will probably be different. So here are the resources you might need to help you connecting to your WCF service are here:

- [WCF .net core at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/)
- [BasicHttpBinding Tests](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/tests/Scenarios/Binding/Http/BasicHttpBindingTests.4.0.0.cs)
- [ClientCredentialType Tests](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/tests/Scenarios/Security/TransportSecurity/Https/ClientCredentialTypeTests.4.1.0.cs)

The tests helped me a lot but they where somewhat hard to find (I had help, thank you Zhenlan for [answering my wcf github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2544))

Comment: what is IAService?

Comment: I-A-Service is just an interface with service model contracts that describe the WCF service take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory

Comment: For anyone else that finds this while searching for a solution. The interface IAService_PortType mentioned @Sturla is the interface that matches your webservice. If you follow this guide to generate https://joshuachini.com/2017/07/13/calling-a-soap-service-from-asp-net-core-or-net-core/ - the interface will exists inside the namespace that you specified during the generation.

Comment: I am getting following Error Any please: 
There was an error in serializing body of message : 'There was an error generating the XML document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Answer (score 7):

To consume a SOAP service from .NET core, adding connected service from the project UI does not work.

**Option 1:**
**Use dotnet-svcutil CLI. 
Prerequisite: VS 2017, Version 15.5 or above**

1. Launch Developer Command Prompt VS 2017.
2. Go to app.csproj file and add below references:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.5.3" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-svcutil" Version="1.0.*" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
3. Rebuild solution.
4. Change directory to your project location from VS command prompt.
5. run command: svcutil SOAP_URL?wsdl ;
   example: example.com/test/testing?wsdl
   This will generate reference files and output.config file in your project.
6. .Net Core does not have any app.config or web.config files, but the output.config file will serve the SOAP binding.

**Option 2**
**In case you need to refer more than one SOAP sevice,**

1. Create a new class library project, use .Net framework 4.5.1
   .Net framework matters as i saw the reference files generated from contract 
   is not correct if .Net Framework is latest.
2. Add service reference by right click on References.
3. Refer the class library project from your .Net core project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used this extension to do t https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: What if it's a .NET Standard class library? Microsoft.AspNetCore.All can't be added in that case...

Comment: @Justin , for your case option 2 mentioned above is applicable.

Comment: `new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)` this won't work and the problem is making connection over WCF with TransportWithMessageCredential.

Comment: Version was updated and 4.6.0 is working very good with TransportWithMessageCredential `<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: The Option 1 worked for me. I had to look for a way to access the service by using             var p = new ServiceName(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("ur service url"));

Comment: Option 2 does not work for wshttpbinding bindings in .NET Core

Comment: Hi, I'm trying Option 2 and getting this exceptions "Only HOST and HTTP service principal names are supported System.InvalidOperationException".i'm using  var upnEndpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(userPrincipalName)

Comment: var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;

Answer (score 6):

So I had to do this and used the [WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide).

The apparent need, according to responses like those here, for all the roundabout business with Bindings and Factories and Proxies seemed strange, considering that this all appeared to be part of the imported class.

Not being able to find a straightforward official "HowTo", I will post my findings as to the **simplest** setup I was able to cobble together to fit my requirements with Digest authentication:

```
    ServiceName_PortClient client = new ServiceName_PortClient();
    //GetBindingForEndpoint returns a BasicHttpBinding
    var httpBinding = client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
    client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Digest");
    var result = await client.GetResultAsync();
```

Now, if you don't need to do any authentication simply doing:

```
    ServiceName_PortClient client = new ServiceName_PortClient();
    var result = await client.GetResultAsync();
```

Should be sufficient.

The `ServiceName_PortClient` class was generated as such by the import tool, where `ServiceName` was the name of the service I was importing.

Of course it seems to be more in the spirit of the imported code to place the configuration in a partial `ServiceName_PortClient` class along the lines of:

```
    public partial class ServiceName_PortClient
    {
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
        {
            var httpBinding = serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
            httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
            clientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Realm");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if I need to add Bearer token?

Answer (score 5):

For those who are trying to do the same with NTLM and .Net Core and wondering what some of the variables are defined as, I clarified the code to look like:

`IAService_PortType` is the service reference you created if you followed the guide on https://joshuachini.com/2017/07/13/calling-a-soap-service-from-asp-net-core-or-net-core/

```cs
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = 
    new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
// Setting it to Transport will give an exception if the url is not https
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = 
    HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

ChannelFactory<IAService_PortType> factory = 
    new ChannelFactory<IAService_PortType>(basicHttpBinding, 
    new EndpointAddress(
        new Uri("https://someurl.com/ws/TheEndpoint.pub.ws:AService")));
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = user;
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = pass;
IAService_PortType serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Open();

try
{
    var result = serviceProxy.getSomethingAsync("id").Result;

}
finally
{
    // cleanup
    factory.Close();
    ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ChannelFactory`class even in pure `dotnet core`. It is fairly simple.

```cs
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://<myhost>/SimpleSOAPService.svc"));
dynamic channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISimpleSOAPService>(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
var result = serviceClient.Ping();
channelFactory.Close();
```

You can find a working GitHub example [here](https://github.com/michaelringholm/soap/tree/master/dotnet/soap-client).

Don't forget to change between `BasicHttpBinding` and `BasicHttpsBinding` depending on whether you are using `HTTP` or `HTTPS` in the `URL`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `There was an error reflecting 'login'` only in a unix (Docker and wsl2) environment.
On Windows there was no problem at all.

I tried to create the connected service via the `dotnet-svcutil` (version 2.0.1), but this didn't solve the issue.

I finally managed to find the root of my problem.
I published my application with the following dotnet command:
`dotnet publish "myapp/myapp.csproj" -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained true -p:PublishTrimmed=true -p:ReadyToRun=true -p:ReadyToRunShowWarnings=true -o publish`

When I removed the attribute `-p:PublishTrimmed=true` it finally worked both under wsl2 and in my docker environment.

Answer (score 1):

I used the .net core 3 svutil to generate the wrapper classes from an old school asmx SOAP / WSDL. See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

I then wrapped the remote and used the code below to set the authentication.  I believe this works for Kerberos and will fall back to NTLM (depending on the headers returned from the server).

```
public class DocumentManagerWrapper
{
    public DocumentManagerWrapper(string serviceUrl,
        String username,
        String password)
    {
        _serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }
    private String _serviceUrl;
    private String _username;
    private String _password;

    private DocumentManagerSoap GetSoapConnection()
    {
        BasicHttpSecurityMode mode = _serviceUrl.StartsWith("https") ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport : BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(mode);

        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(_serviceUrl);

        ChannelFactory<DocumentManagerSoapChannel> channel = new ChannelFactory<DocumentManagerSoapChannel>(binding, address);
        channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = _username;
        channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = _password;
        DocumentManagerSoap soap = channel.CreateChannel();
    
        return soap;
     }
}
```

Note - *DocumentManagerSoapChannel* and *DocumentManagerSoap* classes are generated by svcutil.