# Consuming a WCF service in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, .net-core

I have a WSDL service which worked fine (and is still working in .net 4.x) and fairly newcomer to .NET Core 2.0.

I created the WSDL web service reference (The same steps followed as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

My question is how to consume this service? Do someone know of a good tutorial? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: anybody have any documentation or link where the example we have. This below answers does not explain clearly. Hi @danie, how you do this?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is how to consume this service?

The *[WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)* creates everything you need.

The client is automatically created with all the end-points in the service and any associated classes such as service parameters.

During the *WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool* wizard you specify a namespace for the client, so if you entered `CompanyName.Service` you'd be able to create the client by typing `var client = new CompanyName.Service.ClientName();`

Please note that the name `ClientName` will be generated by the tool, and intelli-sense will you give you the actual name.

Once you have the client you can call any method on the service in the normal way. Such as:

```
var response = client.CancelPolicyAsync(cancelRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the link here:

- Calling a SOAP service in .net Core

  [Calling a SOAP service in .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core)
- How to Call WCF Services and Create SOAP Services with ASP.NET Core

  Click [here](https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/)!

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF service still is on .NET Classic - so nothing changed - you should consume it as always you do as regular WCF service.

What you have done creating WSDL web service reference  - you have created client for **Standard** framework. Put it into separate Standard project. Then it can be referenced in **core** and **classic** frameworks aps.