# .netcore soap Authentication

Tags: authentication, .net-core, soapheader

I am migrating from .netframework to .netCore. I have a webservice for which I am using SoapCore as alternative in .netCore. the webservice has authentication required as SoapHeader. How do i implement that in SoapCore?

Comment: please show us some code and tell us more about what kind of soap service you are consuming. Did you also checked some thread in stackoverflow like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core?

Comment: I am trying to create a soap service using .netcore. I am using middleware(soapcore) to build that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoapMessageInspector.

Have you seen [this](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore)?