# Consume a SOAP Service in an Azure function

Tags: soap, .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-mac

**Environment**

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on MAC, Mono 5.12.0.309

**Problem**

I've successfully built and packaged an Azure Function. Now, I'd like to call a SOAP Web service in the function (over which I have no control). I added a Web Reference to the published WSDL and tried to compile the function which resulted in a ton of errors primarily indicating "System.Web.Services" namespace is missing.

"System.Web" doesn't seem to be part of .NET Core 2.1 (that is referenced in the function project). How would I then add a reference to "System.Web.Services" assembly? Is there a NuGet package?

**UPDATE**

Part of this was my lack of understanding of what .NET Core actually is. Since I'm using .NET Core, I can't make reference to assemblies that are targeting .NET Framework. "System.Web.Services" seems to be one.

Now the question becomes, how one would then call SOAP Services from .NET Core application?

Comment: did you try with regular web requests?

Comment: @Vladislav I could have, but then I had to deal with a lot of things that an auto-generated proxy normally does (e.g.: writing a lot of boilerplate code). I did however find a way. Using the new "dotnet-svcutil" tool I can not only generate the proxy, request and response classes but also add all the required Nuget packages targeting .NET Standard at once.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new WCF client side stack on .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

There is a good sample to a question on this thread: [Calling a SOAP service in .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core)

Comment: That's more or less what I've done (as pointed out in my comment). Thanks. Although, I rather let "svcutil" generate the proxy classes and manage dependencies for me. That made my client side code more succinct compare to that example.