# SOAP request in .net core 2 for a web service

Tags: web-services, soap, .net-core

I'm writing a project in .Net Core 2.2. As a part of it, for the payment service I have to use this web service: [The Payment Web Service](https://pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPGServices/Sale/SaleService.asmx)

**My problem is that I want to make a SOAP request, and I don't exactly know how and there are no available documentation about it!**

I want to use the `SalePaymentRequest` method. The sample code from the bank has the following code which uses in web reference: `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`. Apparently, it is not available in .net core.

In the [Following Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core) there are elements like `BasicHttpBinding` which I really do not understand how to use! (My Bad!)

I just want to make a sale request and verify it afterwards.

Comment: do you seen this Article[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1] ?

Comment: Please make clear what exactly your question is about? For example I don't know if you are looking for a solution to call SOAP requests within .net core? Or your question is about the role of `BasicHttpBinding`?

Comment: @zolfaghari Yeah , I did, Unfortunately I don't know how to use the soap request based on this answer

Comment: @mehrandvd I want to make a SOAP request for a payment gateway in .net core and after some searches, I found out that it may can be done with something like the link below, but it has some variables of `BasicHttpBinding`  : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1)