# How to register dependency injection for the class that implements two interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I wrote a WCF client that I want to consume in my asp.net core service (the client was written based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core/48660543#48660543) post):

```
public class ExternalCompanyClient : IExternalCompanyClient
{
    public async Task<string> CallAsync() 
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://........."));
        ChannelFactory<IExternalCompanyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IExternalCompanyService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
        IExternalCompanyService serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Open();
        var opContext = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)serviceProxy);
        var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current; 
        OperationContext.Current = opContext;

        ExternalCompanyResponse ret = null;

        var request = GetRequest();

        try
        {
            ret = await serviceProxy.GetCompanyInfoAsync(request);

            factory.Close();
            ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            WCFHelpers.CloseCommunicationObjects((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy, factory);
            OperationContext.Current = prevOpContext;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

After that, I just need to register this service via dependency injection:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddExternalCompanyClient(this IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddTransient<IExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyClient>();
```

Now what I want to do is to move on all common code into separate `ServiceCaller` class and use this class for all other WCF clients for the usability purposes.

So, the `ServiceCaller` is as follows (I added the comments to see the differences in `CallAsync` method):

```
internal class ServiceCaller<TInterface, TIn, TOut> where TInterface : IService<TIn, TOut>
{
    private readonly Uri _uri;

    public ServiceCaller(Uri uri)
    {
        var attributes = typeof(TInterface).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), true);

        if (attributes.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Interface {typeof(TInterface).Name} does not have ServiceContract attribute");
        }

        _uri = uri;
    }

    public async Task<TOut> CallAsync(TIn request, TOut valueIfError = default(TOut))
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);   
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(_uri);  // uri is passed into via a constructor
        ChannelFactory<TInterface> factory = new ChannelFactory<TInterface>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
        TInterface serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();  // now the serviceProxy is of type of TInterface

        ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Open();
        var opContext = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)serviceProxy);
        var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current;
        OperationContext.Current = opContext;

        TOut ret = default(TOut);   // the return has TOut type now

        try
        {
            ret = await serviceProxy.InvokeAsync(request);   // and here I invoke the interface method

            factory.Close();
            ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {             
            CloseCommunicationObjects.CloseOrAbort((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy, factory);
            OperationContext.Current = prevOpContext;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

So, I added `IService` interface:

```
public interface IService<TIn, TOut>
{
    Task<TOut> InvokeAsync(TIn request);
}
```

And, finally, my new simplified `ExternalCompanyClient`:

```
public class ExternalCompanyClient : IExternalCompanyClient, IService<ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>
{
    private readonly IExternalCompanyService _externalCompanyService;

    public ExternalCompanyClient(IExternalCompanyService externalCompanyService)
    {
        _externalCompanyService = externalCompanyService;
    }

    private ExternalCompanyRequest GetRequest() =>  // some logic goes here   

    public async Task<string> GetCompanyInfoAsync()
    {
        var request = GetRequest();

        var serviceCaller = new ServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>(
            new System.Uri("http://......................."));

        var result = await serviceCaller.CallAsync(request);

        return result;
    }

    public Task<ExternalCompanyResponse> InvokeAsync(ExternalCompanyRequest request)
    {
        return _externalCompanyService.GetCompanyInfoAsync(request);
    }
}
```

How should I register dependencies for the `ExternalCompanyClient` in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the class and use the factory delegate when registering the individual interfaces

```
public static IServiceCollection AddExternalCompanyClient(this IServiceCollection services) =>
    services
        .AddTransient<ExternalCompanyClient>()
        .AddTransient<IExternalCompanyClient>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ExternalCompanyClient>())
        .AddTransient<IService<ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>>(sp => 
            sp.GetRequiredService<ExternalCompanyClient>()
        );
```

resolving either of the interfaces will provided the derived class.

Note however that based on your shown refactor, `ExternalCompanyClient` is tightly coupled to `ServiceCaller`.

```
var serviceCaller = new ServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>(
        new System.Uri("http://......................."));
```

Ideally, that should also be refactored out into its own abstraction

```
public interface IServiceCaller<TInterface, TIn, TOut> 
    where TInterface : IService<TIn, TOut> {
    Task<TOut> CallAsync(TIn request, TOut valueIfError = default(TOut));
}

internal class ServiceCaller<TInterface, TIn, TOut> : IServiceCaller<TInterface, TIn, TOut> 
    where TInterface : IService<TIn, TOut> {
    //...
}
```

and applied accordingly

```
public class ExternalCompanyClient : IExternalCompanyClient, IService<ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse> {
    private readonly IExternalCompanyService _externalCompanyService;
    private readonly IServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse> serviceCaller;

    public ExternalCompanyClient(IExternalCompanyService externalCompanyService, IServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse> serviceCaller) {
        _externalCompanyService = externalCompanyService;
        this.serviceCaller = serviceCaller
    }

    //...


    public async Task<string> GetCompanyInfoAsync() {
        var request = GetRequest();

        var result = await serviceCaller.CallAsync(request);

        return result;
    }

    //...
}
```

making sure to register the new abstraction.

This results in the previous example being changed to

```
public static IServiceCollection AddExternalCompanyClient(this IServiceCollection services) =>
    services
        .AddTransient<ExternalCompanyClient>()
        .AddTransient<IExternalCompanyClient>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ExternalCompanyClient>())
        .AddTransient<IService<ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>>(sp => 
            sp.GetRequiredService<ExternalCompanyClient>()
        )
        .RegisterTransient<IServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>> (sp => 
            new ServiceCaller<ExternalCompanyClient, ExternalCompanyRequest, ExternalCompanyResponse>(
                new System.Uri("http://......................."))
        );
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But when I register the interfaces using the factory delegate, I get an error: 
`Unable to resolve service for type 'ExternalCompanyClient' while attempting to activate 'ExternalCompanyClient'`. I didn't refactor `ServiceCaller` so far (so, I just use the first snippet of your code - `AddExternalCompanyClient` method).

Comment: @DmitryStepanov recheck the registration code. It should not be trying to resolve the **class** while trying to activiate the same **class**. You may have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong error. The error is as follows: `Unable to resolve service for type 'IExternalCompanyService' while attempting to activate 'ExternalCompanyClient'`.    `IExternalCompanyService` is an interface that was automatically generated when I added WCF service to the project. Should I register it somehow?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov Yes you would need to register all dependencies with the container so that it know how to resolve them.

Comment: Yes. I registered them and no more dependencies errors. While I still have another errors in `ServiceCaller` which are not due to dependencies I accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm stuck with `ServiceCaller` class, so I've asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976249/write-a-helper-class-to-invoke-wcf-services-in-asp-net-core)