# How to see contents of Asp.Net Core SOAP request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap

In Asp.Net Core there is support for generating a SOAP client via Connected Services in Visual Studio.  This SO Questions discusses using that code: [Calling a SOAP service in .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core)

My questions is related to debugging such a service call. Generally to  do that it's super helpful to see the actual xml that comprises the SOAP request that will be sent over the wire to the server.  Is there a way to in Asp.Net Core's SOAP support to see that SOAP xml?

As an aside I even tried to view it using Fiddler, but the request and response are not showing up, even though I have it configured to decrypt HTTPS traffic.  I have found other developers reporting this same issue: https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-no-longer-capturing-web-service-requests-in-net

Is there a way to in Asp.Net Core's SOAP support to see the xml generated for the request?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a same thing, and unfortunately couldn't find a way to see in debugger exactly what XML is sent out, so I'm using a service that can catch any request (like https://webhook.site). I can't configure any response, but at least I can see full XML that is sent out in the request ...

Comment: What service are you using?  Please replace webhooks.site with that service.

Comment: @RonC Sorry - I made a typo -> should be https://webhook.site/ (I placed one extra "s") .. fixed in the original answer