# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services from Blazor project

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, system.web

I have a blazor project in .NET 6.0

I need to call a SOAP WebService (guide [here](https://filebin.net/9nik2hv0hqnrtlsg))

What I do is to import WSDL as Connected Service in another project of my solution with target framework NET4.8

The solution builds correctly, but when I debug and I try to call the method from blazor app I have the following error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context

Now, I suppose it's a .NET version compatibility problem, but how I can solve it?

### EDIT

I try creating a new project .NET 6.0 and adding Connected service.
Calling the method from my blazor (.NET 6.0) project and I have the same error.
Probably the web service use something that is incompatible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the suggested answer below solve your case?

Comment: nope, not solved

Comment: The Blazor project is .Net 6.0; the other project is .Net 4.8. The two frameworks are incompatible which is why you cannot invoke the service from the Blazor project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a SOAP service in .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core)

Comment: @MetroSmurf In the weekend I'm going to check and try this solution and I let you know, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a reference to the NuGet Package `System.Windows.Compatibility`

Comment: thanks but not working