# WCF Basic authentication between Full .NET and .NET Core

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, wcf-binding

I would like to make a WCF https-connection between a .NET core application and a full .NET webservice (Hosted in IIS), with **Basic authentication**.

On the .NET Core side I have a ChannelFactory set up like this:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "abc";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "xyz";
```

On the webservice I have an endpoint using a binding configured like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

But at runtime I get this error message:

> **System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:** 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="localhost"'.'

I was expecting both sides to say *authentication scheme 'Basic'* and to connect without any problems.
I don't know where the **realm** comes from, but I can't get rid of it. I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: Make sure that your password is correct, this issue can occur when there's an issue with the credentials.

Comment: It looks like I don't even get to that point. The server side custom UsernamePasswordValidator doesn't get called.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696777/5077196

Answer (score 0):

You already set credential type basic, then you should use HTTPS ,
https://localhost/....